# SQL Server 2012 prevent user from connecting through Excel to access Tables but allow Views

Tags: sql-server, permissions

I have a database that I want to protect.

The server/database allows mixed authentication.

I want to prevent users that are not logged in to select/insert/update/delete from tables but I want to allow them using the Views I have defined (and maybe some UDFs).

Currently, when user connect to the database using tools like Excel and Access, they have access to everything. I need to limit them. I would like to do it on Public so that everybody using Windows Authentication has access to SOME objects.

How can I do it?

Comment: [This is the link to the MSDN SQL Server Books Online topics for Security](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669074%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - you can read all about how to secure a database and provide only limited access to certain users / groups

Comment: Anything more specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`grant select on (view) to (user)`

Comment: but how to deny/revoke everything else?

Comment: Undo whatever you already gave them access to.  By default, when you give a user access to a database, they only get the Public role, which only allows them to connect.  It doesn't have access to anything in the database.

Comment: You are right. What was misleading is that i was testing on a database created by me (and I have sa permissions).